# JS: Get number of same values

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Suppose i have this array:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

How do i return an array/object that contains how many times a value appears something like:

```
{1:1, 2:2:, 3:3, 4:1}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
// sort first
arr.sort();

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length, i < l, i++) {
    // what should go here ???? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Our results will be loaded into cont
var cont = {};

// For each number in our value array
for ( var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++ ) {
   // If it's found in the result array
   cont[ vals[i] ]
     // Increment it
     ? cont[ vals[i] ]++
     // Else, set it to 1
     : cont[ vals[i] ] = 1 ;
}
```

Could be made even simpler using a while loop and variable assignment:

```
var vals = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], // Values to cycle through
    cont = {},                    // Object to store results in
    indx = i = -1;                // Index and Counting variables

while ( indx = vals[ ++i ] )      // While a value exists for location i
  cont[ indx ]                    // Check to see if it's in the result object
    ? cont[ indx ]++              // If it is, increment it
    : cont[ indx ] = 1 ;          // If it is not, set it to 1
```

Comment: @J0HN i think you meant unreadable and unmaintainable edition :P

Comment: @jbabey Ternary operators are easily understood by most developers. There's nothing too cryptic about this solution. Now, the logical operator that was used earlier on could be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

what you're looking for is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram):

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/jdMgp/

```
var array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4];
var results = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (results.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) {
        results[array[i]]++;
    } else {
        results[array[i]] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(results);​
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to sort.

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (!result[arr[i]]) {
        result[arr[i]]=0;
    }
     result[arr[i]]+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]; // Sample data
var countings = {}; // Result object
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(countings[(arr[i])] == undefined) countings[(arr[i])] = 0;
    countings[(arr[i])]++;
}
```

[Fiddle goes here.](http://jsfiddle.net/m9j8d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Array `forEeach`  method:

```
var freq = {}, arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4];
arr.forEach(function(x){
   freq[x] = freq[x] ? freq[x]+1 : 1;
});
//=> freq[1] = 1, freq[2] = 2, freq[3] = 3 and freq[4] = 1
//=> arr is still [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You'd probably just use `forEach` since you're not using the generated Array.